# Share Count Missing After Adding OpenGraph Tags to Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I built a page at the following URL http://s2r.ca/helpmetest that had been shared a couple of times. When I viewed the Facebook Graph API stats on the page it showed that the page had 2 shares.

I then proceeded to add Open Graph tags to the page so that when the page is shared a specific image, title and description would be displayed. Since adding these tags, when I view the Graph API stats, the 'shares' key is missing from the result set.

Looking at the graph debugger, other than a warning that my image needs to be at least 200px x 200 px (which is it ~600 x ~300, unless it wants the image to be square, but it pulls the image anyways and the Share box also pulls it when clicking the Facebook button from the website), there aren't any errors.

So I'm a little confused as to why the counts have gone missing.

Since then, I have shared the site at the following 2 urls:
http://s2r.ca/helpmetest
http://s2r.ca/helpmetest/0

and the Graph API request still doesn't return any shares
http://graph.facebook.com/http://s2r.ca/helpmetest
http://graph.facebook.com/http://s2r.ca/helpmetest/0

Does anyone have any insight as to why?

Comment: The odd thing is the Insights tab of the Facebook app is showing 4 shares, so it looks like Facebook is recording them they're just not being returned by the Graph API call

Comment: So it looks like the value of what "shares" means changed after adding those tags. Previously it was showing the number of times the link was included in a Post, now it is only showing the number of times the Post has been Shared using the 'share' button on the post in Facebook.